# How to alternate values of a =textjoin range in spreadsheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

first of all excuse my poor English, I'm trying to get the exact words to summarize my problem.

I'm trying to make a formula to concatenate a big range of cells by alternating its crossed values.

[image: expected values and actual output]

If you see the image, I have some titles (3rd row), and some variable values for each column from B to D, in the rows 5 to 7. The number of columns and rows will expand in actual project. Then, I need to summarize all crossed data to make some processes later: I need the output written at column F, where I get the title and then the cell value.

If I use `=TEXTJOIN(",";;"$B$3:$D$3;B5:D5)` I get the output at H5, but It makes me to get many problems later at processing information.

I have tried to make some extra columns or cells concatenating content of each "title" and "value", and then, joining everything, but it's a poor solution if I'm trying to build a sheet with hundreds of columns. I'm sure there would be another better solution, but I can't figure out by now.

Answer (score 1):

your formula should be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B5:D<>"", ","&B3:D3&","&B5:D, )),,999^99)), "^,", ), " ,", ","))
```

[image]